# How to run monkeytalk scripts each time with new data?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, monkeytalk

We are using eclipse luna 4.4.1, adb is installed on linux system to test android app.

I have recorded a monkeytalk script. So my question is how to run that monkeytalk recorded script in 500 times. But in every loop the value of input data should be change(Validation stuff).
For example : I recorded sign up account. So that need to run it 500 times to create 500 diffrent account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use *parameterization*.

It's simply when you use variables in your script instead of hardcoded values. That gives you an opportunity to assign new values to that variables with each new run.

Here is an example from [official documentation](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/parameterized-scripts) regarding parametrizing the script:

```
Vars * Define usr="default-at-example.com" pwd
 Input username EnterText ${usr}
 Input password EnterText ${pwd}
 Button LOGIN Tap
```

In this listing you can see that you've defined "usr" variable with default value ("default-at-example.com").

As a result, you can invoke you parametrized script in a number of different
ways.

In this case "pwd" variable will have "i like cheese" value:

```
Script login.mt Run joe-at-doe.com "i like cheese"
```

Following example shows script invocation without specifying any arguments for variables:

```
Script login.mt Run * password1
```

It'll have following effect: variable "usr" will have its' default value and "pwd" variable will have "password1" value

Don't forget that those variables' scope is limited only to the script. It means that they're visible and can be used only inside of script where they have been defined.

Moreover you can use [external data sources](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/data-driven-scripts) in order to feed your tests with data. It's called *data driven testing*. Here is an example of script which uses *.csv file (coma separated) as such data source:

```
//data.csv

joe-at-doe.com, "i like cheese"
alpha-at-beta.net, password1
charlie-at-dog.org, abc123
```

In order to use such *.csv file just run following command:

```
 Script login.mt RunWith data.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor, i will implement it and let you know.

Comment: Hi Viktor, sorry for late reply, i have one question, if i am using login script to run 500 times as using data driven, so my question is where should i mention that script will run in 500 times? or i should just give the input values 500 times in .csv file?

Comment: Exactly, you have to copy-paste those values 500 times to your xls file. In this case each new line will represent a test.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, i will try and and let you know.

Comment: Hello Viktor,
Please do comment on my below question.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650501/i-want-to-access-contact-list-of-my-phone-using-monkeytalk